# Could wave packet spreading of the universe explain the low entropy of the early universe?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, entropy, big-bang

[Entropy of position and wave packet spreading](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0034487786900054).

[Why do wave packets spread out over time](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77860/31339)?

[Wave packet of the universe and its  spreading](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10773-015-2840-7).

[Why was the universe in such an extraordinarily low entropy state right after the big bang?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18702/31339)

Is there a connection between the spreading of the wave packet of the universe and the [time arrow](https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2004/10/27/the-arrow-of-time/)  , despite the reversible character of physical laws? Could this be an explanation of the low entropy state of the early universe?

In other words,  could wave packet spreading  of the universe  explain the low entropy (low compared  to  later entropy) of the early universe? Note that the wave packet spreading of the early universe can be justified mathematically,  with no need for  any physical hypothesis.

Comment: " with no need for any physical hypothesis"  , except that wave packets model the universe of course, that is a physical hypothesis

Comment: Recent related question by same OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/499660/is-there-a-connection-between-the-spreading-of-the-wave-packet-of-the-universe-a

Comment: As always when I read your comments/answers  @annav . Correct.

Comment: @GSmith  I  felt my previous question was misunderstood.

Comment: people interested see my answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/499660/is-there-a-connection-between-the-spreading-of-the-wave-packet-of-the-universe-a

Comment: If you thought your previous question was misunderstood, why did you accept anna v’s answer?

Comment: I think the question was misunderstood by the author of the other answer there. On the other hand, anna  v's answer not only clarifies both questions,  but gives you a  deeper insight.

Comment: Also chronology is important @GSmith  , look at the time stamps.